# Method does not override any method from its superclass (Swift 4, Xcode 9)

Tags: swift

I've checked few topics related with the same issue but I can't find any solution to this problem inside my own code...

The error occurs when I try to override the function tune() in my Piano: Instrument subclass.

I've copy/past the superclass original function to ensure that the syntax is strictly the same.

Also, it seems to me that the subclass is well done, because the super.init method seems to work as intended (no compiler error).

Please, can someone point out to me where is my error ?

The code :

```
class Music {

    let notes: [String]

    init(notes: [String]) {
        self.notes = notes
    }

    func prepared() -> String {
        return notes.joined(separator: " ")
    }

}

class Instrument {

    let model: String

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model

        func tune() -> String {
            fatalError("Implement this method for \(model)")
        }

        func play(_ music: Music) -> String {
            return music.prepared()
        }

        func perform(_ music: Music) {
            print(tune())
            print(play(music))
        }

    }

}

class Piano: Instrument {

    let hasPedals: Bool

    init(hasPedals: Bool, model: String) {
        self.hasPedals = hasPedals
        super.init(model: model)

    }

    override func tune() -> String {
        fatalError("Implement this method for \(model)")
    }

}

class Guitar: Instrument {

    let hasAmplifyer: Bool

    init(hasAmplifyer: Bool, model: String) {
        self.hasAmplifyer = hasAmplifyer
        super.init(model: model)

    }

}
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accidentally defined your `tune`, `play`, and `perform` functions inside of your `init` function.  Move them to the top level:

```
class Instrument {

    let model: String

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
    }

    func tune() -> String {
        fatalError("Implement this method for \(model)")
    }

    func play(_ music: Music) -> String {
        return music.prepared()
    }

    func perform(_ music: Music) {
        print(tune())
        print(play(music))
    }

}
```

Swift sees no `tune` function to override because it expects it to be at the top level in `Instrument`.